# How get the value of an Nunit Custom Attribute

Tags: methods, attributes, nunit

I'm using NUNIT. I want to retrieve some tests of a certain kind from the Nunit test DLL.

I have defined a Custom Attribute which I then assign to the test method like so:

```
    [Test, Tier(Tier.Second)]
    public void ThisIsMyTest()
    { ... }
```

This is my Custiom Attibute definition:

```
 public enum Tier
{
    First = 1,
    Second,
    Third,
    Fourth
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TierAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public TierAttribute(Tier tier)
        : base(tier)
    { }
}
```

Now I would like to Select methods that use my custom attrib with certain Tier value.

First I load my assembly:

```
Type loadTests = ltAssm.GetType("Assm.Tests.LoadTests." + args[0]);
```

Then I attempt to retrieve only the tests adorned with the attribute:

```
 List<MethodInfo> tests = loadTests.GetMethods()
                                   .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TierAttribute), true).Count() > 0).ToList<MethodInfo>()
                                   .Where(t => (((t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TierAttribute), true).GetValue(0)))).ToString() == args[1]).ToList<MethodInfo>();
```

But It's coming up empty.

By the way, I have tried it without the first WHERE clause in the above statement (and only used the second), but that issues an index out of range error.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What happens if you take the second WHERE clause off?

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need the ToList() on the first where clause.  In fact, if you don't need to add/remove (i.e. you're just going to iterate) from the list you could probably just leave it as IEnumerable.